# Should I use a single denoising method with aggressive settings, or combine different methods?

Tags: software, post-processing, noise-removal

I shot some pictures at night, at ISO 3200, and they are of course extremely noisy. But I want to keep them, and make them as decently looking as I can.

I use Darktable as a workflow software, and it offers four different plugins for denoise. I don't know how any of them works, but even if I knew the underlying principle, I'm not so good at photographic theory to know which one would be best for my pictures. Usually I just pick one at random and leave it at the default presets. But with these extremely noisy pictures, I need stronger denoise.

So I was wondering, should I choose one method of denoise and turn the slider up until I can't stand the blur? Or is it better to use several denoising techniques at once, in the hope that they have different disadvantages which don't stack?

I post the different denoise modules here, maybe some of you can recognize their working principle based on their names and parameters they have.

[image: equalizer]

[image: non-local]

[image: bilateral]

[image: raw]

I think that "equalizer" is uncommon, it is a tool for enhancing local contrast for different sizes of structures. It has a "denoise" preset, too. The others are pure denoise tools. The documentation says "raw denoise" comes from dcraw.

Answer (score 2):

As you mention there are several denoise plugins in Darktable, they differs in the algorithm how they will fight noise, speed, artifacts produced, resource usage etc.

denoise (non-local means) - works on luma (lightness noise) and chroma (color noise)

denoise (bilateral filter) - works on each channel (R,G,B noise)

equalizer (exotic wavelets) - i suppose this works on both luma/chroma

rawdenoise - does only work on chroma noise and is faster then the others

I have no deep insight into those algorithms used but the most common used for
fighting ISO noise is using raw denoise, i also tend to use normal blending with 
raw denoise to bring back details using the opacity slider.

Comment: You've provided some insight into how the different denoise work, but haven't answered the question directly - "So I was wondering, should I choose one method of denoise and turn the slider up until I can't stand the blur? Or is it better to use several denoising techniques at once, in the hope that they have different disadvantages which don't stack?"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is helpful as a part of the workflow:

Do open a 2nd instance of equalizer.

- In one instance use sharpen - blend [all] - LAB-Modus: L (gray-value)
- In the other instance use denoise - blend [all] - LAB-Modus: AB  (color-values)

Try to change the graphics value: https://www.darktable.org/usermanual/ch03s04s04.html.php

Use also Denoise-RAW (threshold maybe ~0.05) and Denoise-profile, blend [on] and reduce the value if required by %.